# Como traer datos con php y mysqli pero que sean de los últimos 7 días

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo la siguiente consulta con mysqli que me trae registros de una base de datos:

```
<table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ESTADO</th>
                                    <th>FLOTA</th>
                                    <th>EQUIPO</th>
                                    <th>FECHA SALIDA</th>
                                    <th>CAMBIOS</th>
                                    <th>TRABAJO</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<?php

$termi=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `trabajos` where estado_kal='Finalizado' order by fecha DESC");
while($traterm = mysqli_fetch_array($termi)){

?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><?php echo $traterm['estado_kal']; ?></th>
                                    <td><?php echo $traterm['flota_kal']; ?</td>
                                    <td><?php echo $traterm['equipo_kal']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $traterm['fecha_fin']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $traterm['cambios_kal']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $traterm['trabajo_kal']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
<?php
            }       
?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Como puedo hacer para traer solo registros de los últimos 7 días comenzando desde los días jueves, ejemplo: la consulta debe traer todos los registros de los últimos 7 días comenzando desde el jueves y cuando termine los 7 días vuelve a comenzar desde el día jueves pero por supuesto una fecha posterior.

Me seria de gran utilidad cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar. muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece una pregunta muy extensa. 1)Tienes qué averiguar en qué día estás, 2) hacer la resta, 3) modificar tu consulta en tu where fecha_fin>=al resultado que hayas obtenido.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por tu tiempo muy amable de tu parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `interval` en tu consulta MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `trabajos` WHERE estado_kal='Finalizado'
AND fecha >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: sos groso muchas gracias por tu respuesta eso me ayuda bastante ya que me trae información solo de los últimos 7 días.